# I encountered an error while referencing a variable in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, backend, laravel-blade

So I have the following code in my blade file but I keep getting a certain error when it tries to read the variables from the backend.

```
{!! (FALSE === $planTier['element']['badge'] ? '' : 
                        "<div class='pricing__badge-bg'></div>
                        <div class='pricing__badge-text'>
                        <b>
                            <span class = 'content'>
                                {!! $content['text']['UB5JeV']['displayText'] !!}
                            </span>
                        </b>
                        </div>") 
!!}
```

I keep seeing the following error

```
syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting '-' or identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)
```

I think it's the way I'm referencing the variables, I've tried changing the braces from {!! !!} to {{ }} but that didn't work

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: You need to use `@if` in your blade template properly. Check this https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#if-statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you tried to escape the twice. Try this code below.

```
{!! (FALSE === $planTier['element']['badge'] ? '' : 
     "<div class='pricing__badge-bg'></div>
          <div class='pricing__badge-text'>
             <b>
           <span class = 'content'>
           " . $content['text']['UB5JeV']['displayText'] . " 
            </span>
           </b>
      </div>") 
!!}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```html
@if($planTier['element']['badge'])
    <div class="pricing__badge-bg"></div>
    <div class="pricing__badge-text">
    <b>
        <span class="content">
            {{ $content['text']['UB5JeV']['displayText'] }}
        </span>
    </b>
@endif
```